# Selecting the correct form in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML form with at least two forms in, each with the class 'myform' applied. The input buttons in each have a different id, and once clicked should send the data to a database. The problem is the javascript, which stops the refresh and controls buttons states doesn't select the right form - it always sends the details of the form closest to the script... here are the html forms.

```
<div class="booking_box">
<form method="post" class='myform'>
<button class="button" id='b2' name = "8">Book room 8</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="salutation" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["salutation"]?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["firstname"]?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="room" value="8">
    <input type="hidden" name="period" value="1">
</form>
</div>

<div class="booking_box">
<form method="post" class='myform'>
<button class="button" id='b3' name = "7">Book room 7</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="salutation" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["salutation"]?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["firstname"]?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="room" value="7">
    <input type="hidden" name="period" value="1">
</form>
</div>
```

Here is the script at the bottom of the page. I've tried '.closest' and '.parent' but nothing seems to work. I've also tried adding these to the '$.post' section, but then the data is sent to the DB but it's empty fields. Confused...

```
<script>
$("button").click(function() {
    var myID = ($(this).attr('id'));
    var theName = ($(this).attr('name'));
    var isAdd = $("#" + myID).text();

    if (isAdd == "Book room " + theName){
        $('#' + myID).text(isAdd ? 'Cancel room' + theName : 'Book room ' + theName);
        $('#' + myID).closest('.myform').attr('action', isAdd ? 'bookRoom.php' : 'update.php');
    } else {
        $('#' + myID).text(isAdd ? 'Book room ' + theName : 'Cancel room ' . theName);
        $('#' + myID).closest('.myform').attr('action', isAdd ? 'update.php' : 'bookRoom.php');

    }

    $('.myform').submit(function(){
        return false;
    });

    $.post(
        $('.myform').attr('action'),
        $('.myform :input').serializeArray(),
        function(result){
            $('#result').html(result);
        }
    );  
});
</script>
```

As always, any help would be massively appreciated!

Comment: If you are looking to select each form individually, would you consider giving each form an `id=form1` and `id=secondform` or something and with jQuery select `$('#form1')`?

Comment: You shouldn't be binding the `submit` handler inside the `$("button").click()` handler. That means the binding will only apply to a submission done **after** you first click. In general, it's almost always wrong to bind one event handler inside another.

Comment: How would I know which form to select? Ideally, I'd like the form to be identified once the button inside it has been clicked.

Comment: Instead of `button.click` handle `$('.myform').submit`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use `$(this).closest(".myform")` to get the form that should be submitted.

It's also not necessary to use `$("#" + myID)`, since that's the same as `$(this)`.

And the submit handler that prevents normal submission should not be inside the click handler.

```
$('.myform').submit(function(){
    return false;
});

$("button").click(function() {
    var theName = ($(this).attr('name'));
    var isAdd = $(this).text();
    var form = $(this).closest(".myform");

    if (isAdd == "Book room " + theName){
        $(this).text(isAdd ? 'Cancel room' + theName : 'Book room ' + theName);
        form.attr('action', isAdd ? 'bookRoom.php' : 'update.php');
    } else {
        $(this).text(isAdd ? 'Book room ' + theName : 'Cancel room ' . theName);
        form.attr('action', isAdd ? 'update.php' : 'bookRoom.php');
    }

    $.post(
        form.attr('action'),
        form.serialize(),
        function(result){
            $('#result').html(result);
        }
    );  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the event to get the form from the button. Define "e" in your function and e will be the event, e.target is the button, and e.target.form is the form. (tested with jquery 2.2.4)

```
$("button").click(function(e) {
    var myID = ($(this).attr('id'));
    var theName = ($(this).attr('name'));
    var isAdd = $("#" + myID).text();

var frm = e.target.form;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either choose to set the `id` of both forms, for example:

```
<form method="post" class='myform' id="form1">...</form>
<form method="post" class='myform' id="form2">...</form>
```

Or if you do not want to set an `id`, you can use `:nth-child`, for example:

```
$('.myform:nth-child(1)') //will select the 1st form
$('.myform:nth-child(2)') //will select the 2nd form
```

Answer (score 0):

just add another class to forms like

```
<div class="booking_box">
<form method="post" class='myform 8'>
<button class="button" id='b2' name = "8">Book room 8</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="salutation" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["salutation"]?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["firstname"]?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="room" value="8">
    <input type="hidden" name="period" value="1">
</form>
</div>

<div class="booking_box">
<form method="post" class='myform 7'>
<button class="button" id='b3' name = "7">Book room 7</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="salutation" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["salutation"]?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["firstname"]?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="room" value="7">
    <input type="hidden" name="period" value="1">
</form>
</div>
```

Now in your script, you are already getting the button id as "7" or "8". Use this **"myID"** for selecting forms.

Add this to your script.

```
$('.myform').each(function( index ) {
              if($(this).hasClass(myID)){
                  $(this).submit(function(){
                        return false;
                    });
              }
});
```

It just iterate over your all form having "myform" as class and check if they are also having a class as "7" or "8" fetched from the button pressed.

https://api.jquery.com/each/

https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the current form of your buttons, you can use `.closest()`. When you have the current form, you can extract all the information (input) inside.

You can do this:

```
$("button").click(function () {
            var currentForm = $(this).closest("form");
            var actionForm = $(currentForm).attr('action');

            $.post(
                actionFormF,

                $(currentForm).find('input').serializeArray(),
                function (result) {
                    $('#result').html(result);
                }
            );
        });
```